# Work of Omar Khayyam on cubic equations

Tags: reference-request, math-history, reference-works

I am trying to see the work of Omar Khayyam on cubic equations.

It seems that he solved some types of cubic equations.

However, I am not getting proper references for it.

> Can anybody suggest a reference/references which "shows" original work of Omar Khayyam (means information with pictures from his book), and which gives clear information of what type of cubic equations he solved?

---

**Note:** I am not looking only references as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571640/omar-khayyams-method-for-solving-cubics), but which give pictures from his book, as much as possible.

Comment: [Netz, The Transformation of Mathematics in the Early Mediterranean World](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Transformation_of_Mathematics_in_the/kTDRJwCCMecC?hl=en) has a detailed discussion with references. Khayyam solved all types of cubics with positive coefficients but geometrically, by intersecting conic sections.

Comment: Here is [French translation of Khayyam's Algebra](https://www.amazon.fr/Lalg%C3%A8bre-dOmar-Alkhayy%C3%A2m%C3%AE-accompagn%C3%A9e-manuscrits/dp/0543969797/ref=sr_1_26?ie=UTF8&qid=1380029771&sr=8-26&keywords=khayy%C3%A2m) if you want the source.

Comment: https://folk.ntnu.no/hanche/blog/khayyam.pdf